# Como limitar o tamanho mínimo da tela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou trabalhando com o Bootstrap.

O que desejo é que o usuário consiga diminuir a tela até 700px e a partir do momento em que tiver com 700px a tela não diminua mais.

Pode ser via Jquery, JavaScript, no próprio JAVA ou apenas pelo CSS, qualquer forma ajuda.

Obrigado.

Comment: `body { min-width: 700px; }` deve resolver.

Comment: Citar esta propriedade no Código não impede o usuário de diminuir a tela, só diz que o tamanho mínimo ao carregar sera de 700px. Obrigado

Comment: se você está falando à falar da janela do browser, felizmente esta está alem do alcance ;D

Comment: O ideal seria usar media queries, e definir que propriedades e valores você deseja para cada tamanho ou a partir de determinado tamanho de ecran. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer limitar o tamanho da janela do browser, não dá.
Você só poderia fazer isso se você abrisse a janela com `window.open()`, fazendo algo assim:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if(window.outerWidth < 700) {
        window.resizeTo(700, window.outerHeight);
    }
}, true);
```

Agora, se quer limitar o tamanho do corpo da página, faça isso com CSS:

```
body {
  min-width: 700px;
}
```